# deduct or add quantity by user input

Tags: java, sql

i have information about product in database with include `barcode` and so on. In my applications when user key in `barcode` , i only want the first two string of `barcode` such as `rl0001` , i only want `rl` then find in the database and match the corresponding product to deduct/add the quantity.. can u guys help me . this in sql .. TQ

[image: product table]

Comment: please share your table schema

Comment: @DarkRob . done sir

Comment: @DarkRob  how to get first two string from user input to match with data in db . such as user input rl0001 or rl0002 but i only want rl and match data in db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this. As you said in `SQL`. Please find this link for more details about LIKE, [LIKE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions007.htm).

For your query you may use this.

```
 select * from yourtable where barcode like 'rl%'
```

Use `%` with `like` to get the result of any string starts with particular string

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged this as Java, here is the Java answer:
To get the first two chars of the barcode, use the substring method:

```
String barcode = "rl0001";
String twoChars = barcode.substring(0,2)
```

As you tagged ths with SQL as well, here is the SQL answer:
Similar to java, use the [substring method](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT Barcode, Substring(String, 1,2) as START, (...)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Looks, like he wants to filter out rows by only first 2 characters of barcode, so I think, you should add 3rd solution to your answer: use `where barcode like ?` and format parameter as `"rl%"`.

Comment: i see @TEXHIK . oke let me try first

Comment: @meiswjn how about if from user input?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: how the java look likes if the input is varies from user but to get first two string only and filter the row by that.. such as i may get rl0001,rl0002,rl0003 , i just want rl char to match in db..is it possible to achieve :) @Meiswjn

Comment: The Javacode for getting "rl" is in the answer above :)